# Group list elements by condition. Positive or negative

Tags: list-manipulation

The list1 contains positive or negative values. I need to group them as shown in the list2.

```
list1={1,2,3,-1,-2,1,2,3,4,-1,-2,-3}

list2={{1,2,3},{-1,-2},{1,2,3,4},{-1,-2,-3}
```

Comment: SplitBy[list1, If[# > 0, 1, -1] &]

Comment: SplitBy[list1, UnitStep]

Comment: `SplitBy[list1, Sign]`

Answer (score 2):

```
Split[list1, Positive @* Times]
```

> {{1, 2, 3}, {-1, -2}, {1, 2, 3, 4}, {-1, -2, -3}}